# Experimental Data for Contact Angles

Tags: fluid-dynamics, experimental-physics, resource-recommendations, fluid-statics, data

I am doing some experiments with contact angle of liquids on chrome stainless steel and was wondering if in the literature there is already experimental data for contact angles of different fluids on different types of surface.  I am certain that this data has to exist somewhere, so I'm wondering if there is some particle review or research article where it is collated.

Comment: Exactly what are you trying ti measure?

Comment: I was being a bit unclear sorry, I am studying sphere impacts on a body of liquid where the type of liquid is varied (an example liquid might be 5 cSt silicone oil.  The spheres are chrome stainless steel ball bearings.  It would be useful to know the contact angles of different liquids on chrome steel, as otherwise I have to try to measure it, and I feel like there most be existing experimental databases on contact angles.

Comment: Are you looking for bounce, penetration depth, wave generation, what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find tables of this sort of data within the materials science literature under key words *wettability, spreading, capillary rise, contact angle,* and *surface energy.*

You will also find surface energy test fluid sets consisting of ranked series of specially-prepared chemical solutions with distinct and well-controlled surface energies. placing droplets of these fluids on a test sample allows you to estimate the surface energy of that sample, by observing whether the test fluid balls up into spheres or spreads out into a film on the surface.

Comment: I've done many searches and not sure if what I'm looking for exists, I would simply like the contact angle for a regular chrome stainless steel sample when a droplet is placed on it of different liquids: 2 cSt glycerol solution, for example, or silicone oil.  It seems like the literature often assumes that you either talking about a modified surface and/or contact angle of water?